# Javascript validation to allow maximum of 3 commas and 20 character in 1 comma?

Tags: javascript

Javascript validation to allow maximum of 3 commas and 20 character in 1 comma?

```
$('#txt_tags').keyup(function () {
    var tags = $(this).val().split(',');

    if (tags.length > 13)
        alert('there is more than 13 tags');
});
```

Comment: `tags` will be an array. You will have to loop over it

Comment: you can use regular expression test.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to iterate over the array of tags and check their length.

```js
$('#txt_tags').keyup(function () {
    var tags = $(this).val().split(',');

    if (tags.length > 13)
        alert('there is more than 13 tags');

    tags.forEach(function(tag){
       if(tag.length > 20)
         alert("Tag has more than 20 characters");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt_tags" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#txt_tags').keyup(function () {
    if($(this).val().match(/^([^,]*,){14,}|([^,]{21,})/g))
        alert("NOT VALID!");
});

([^,]*,) --> match every comma separated by every char except comma
{14,} --> match it 14 or more time
| --> or
[^,] --> every char except comma
{21,} --> match it 21 or more time
```